# How to add display button on check on checkbox

Tags: flutter, button, checkbox

I am displaying a list of week using `CheckboxGroup`, now i want if user check any checkbox, let say if user check the monday checkbox then it should display button in front of it. the design should look like this

[image]

`CheckboxGroup` code is here

```
Container(
                  // padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 70),
                    child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                        child: SizedBox(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.45,
                            child: ListTile(
                              title: CheckboxGroup(
                                  onChange: (bool isChecked, String label,
                                          int index) =>
                                      setState(() {
                                        day = isChecked;
                                       
                                      }),
                                  labelStyle:
                                      GoogleFonts.montserrat(fontSize: 15),
                                  labels: <String>[
                                    "Monday",
                                    "Tuesday",
                                    "Wednesday",
                                    "Thursday",
                                    "Friday",
                                    "Saturday",
                                    "Sunday",
                                  ],
                                  onSelected: (List<String> checked) =>
                                      ),
                            ))),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    picktimebutton(),
                  ],
                ))
```

I am trying to do it like this but it shows this result

[image]

here is the code of  `picktimebutton()`

```
picktimebutton() {
    if (day == true) {
      return customButton(context, "Pick Time", (){}, 
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.3, 40.0);
    } else {
      return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 70),
          child:
              Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, children: []));
    }
  }
```

please help if anyone know how to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `smart_select` package from `https://pub.dev`

See below link

https://pub.dev/packages/smart_select

Comment: can u please explain more on it? i'm getting from it what i want